# Why in Brazilian Portuguese the "de" and "te" started sounding like /dzhi/ and /tzhi/?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronúncia, fonemas

From [English and Portuguese consonant phonemes compared](http://www.sk.com.br/sk-conso.html):

> Whenever **/t/** or **/d/** occur before /i/, they become respectively **/tshi/**
>   and **/dzhi/**, as in words like *leite* ['leytshi] and *pode* ['pódzhi].

I'm presuming these new (but relatively old) sounds were due to a mix of dialects that induced their creation in Brazil, i.e in Portugal *"de"* sounds like *the* but in Brazil it sounds like *djee* or even *gee*...

However "*do*" sounds the same in both countries (*doo*). I couldn't find why this change occurred though, any ideas?

---

N'[As consoantes do Inglês e do Português](http://www.sk.com.br/sk-conso.html):

> Sempre que **/t/** e **/d/** ocorrem antes de /i/, transformam-se
>   respectivamente em **/tshi/** e **/dzhi/**, como nas palavras *leite* ['leytshi] e *pode* ['pódzhi].

Presumo que estes sons, na altura da sua criação, tenham sido influenciados por algum dialeto já existente no Brasil. Porém não encontrei referências, alguém sabe o porquê?

Comment: Excelente pergunta também nunca percebi o fenômeno.

Comment: Eu percebi quando fui pros EUA e falei "dinner" (/dzhi/nner) e não entendiam o que eu falava, pois entendiam que eu estava falando "ginner"... É uma boa dúvida, apesar de algumas regiões do Brasil se falar "dia" com som de "d" mesmo, e "tia" também com o som de "t" também (não sei escrever essas duas pronúncias).

Comment: It’s affrication due to the high vowel following the dental, just as in English "Didja eat yet?" BTW, it would be better to use the International Phonetic Alphabet for this.

Comment: Aqui no sul, tirando a região metropolitana e capital, temos uma pronuncia mais marcada do TE e DE, mas cada vez menos.

Comment: @Math Pois é, "ginner" não faz sentido nenhum! rsrsrs

Comment: I don't understand your romanization, like /tshi/ or /dzhi/. The `/` seems to suggest you're using phonemic notation, but you're not. Where did this notation come from?

Comment: @Earthliŋ From the [website I quoted](http://www.sk.com.br/sk-conso.html), it does seem different, but it's clear that they were trying to "explain" a sound.

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked all links before asking. I might be back with questions later ;)

Comment: É interessante notar que esse fenômeno tem análogos fora do português. No francês do Quebec, por exemplo, "d" e "t" antes de /i/ e /y/ também são modificados, embora de uma maneira um pouco diferente que no Brasil (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology#Consonants). O francês europeu, por outro lado, não as modifica da mesma maneira nesse contexto.

Comment: I know this question is old and I believe your doubts were solved, but I am curious about this part: "Portugal "de" sounds like the but in Brazil ..."
I am brazillian so I can't say it for you, of the D sounding as TH (the voiced one).
But some accents in Brazil influenced by Portuguese-PT they pronounce D as D. Sometimes occurs of someone touch the teeth in saying T or D, so it produces an approximant TH sound (that I can't difference in my ears, just see the movement when they speak), but never saw someone using the canonical form of the TH sound (a little longer) instead D.

Comment: The "canonical form" I refer is that one that they teach us for trainning, that is longer and has more emphasys. The same way someone who has a lisp would say a S or a Z continuously.

Answer (score 8):

In many Brazilian Portuguese accents, [e] is "reduced" to [ɪ] or [i] when unstressed. Since the articulation of [ɪ] is similar to of [j]¹ (the later being the "y" sound in "yes"), what once was pronounced as [te] or [de] could possibly have started to be pronounced as [tʲi] and [dʲi] and progressed to [tʃi] and [dʒi], as it is nowadays. This process is called palatalization.

I don't really know why all this happened, but I assume it is just the natural evolution of the language. As Marcelo Silva noted, though, this is commom for São Paulo accent and it is possible that it's been spread to other regions through the media.

It's interesting to note, however, that these phenomena don't always occur the way I described. For instance, in my accent (I'm from Paraná), the palatalization occurs, but the reduction is less common. Thus, I pronounce "noite" as ['noj.te], but "tia" as ['tʃi.a]. On the other hand, in some regions (Northeast, usually) there is a reduction, but not the palatalization (thus "noite" is rendered as ['noj.tɪ] and "tia" as ['ti.a]).

¹From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant):

> The palatal approximant is the semivocalic equivalent of the close
>   front unrounded vowel [i]. The two are almost identical featurally.
>   They alternate with each other in certain languages, such as French,
>   and in the diphthongs of some languages, ⟨j⟩ and ⟨i̯⟩ with the
>   non-syllabic diacritic are used in different transcription systems to
>   represent the same sound.

Answer (score 4):

Como nativo, e não especialista na área, acredito que seja mais fácil, rápido, suave e fluído, a pronúncia desta forma.

Imagino que seja parte do sotaque paulistano, dado que se observa isso de forma mais marcante por lá. E, considerando que as grandes emissoras de televisão e rádio favorecem o sotaque paulistano em detrimento de outros, não é de se espantar que tal fenômeno passe a ser observado em outras regiões, com cada vez mais frequência.

Comment: `mais fácil, rápido, suave e fluído` dizer "podji" do que dizer "pod"? Não faz sentido para mim, enquanto europeu.

Comment: @ANeves, a pronúncia portuguesa, creio, é ainda mais enfática nisso. Mas, eu tava comparando com as que o "i" no final é bem marcante, como do nordeste brasileiro, que realmente soaria como "pódê".

Comment: É mais fácil falar relaxado podji do que o travado pod, sim

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, a evolução da fonética a que se refere, para /**tshi**/ e /**dzhi**/, ocorreu apenas no Brasil. A pronúncia nos *PALOP* (países africanos de língua oficial portuguesa) também difere da portuguesa europeia mas, ainda assim, sofreu uma evolução fonética diferente da brasileira.

Answer (score 0):

Lembro que quando iniciei a aprender português li que é comum a palatalização **/t/** e **/d/** em alguns dialetos de países africanos, e que passou a ser palatalizado no português nos países africanos (não tenho como colocar alguma referência). Então, provavelmente no brasil a palatalização entrou pela população de origem africano. Mas não sei se acontece nos países africanos nos que se fala português. Já de origem nativo-americano vejo menos provável, porque não conheço nenhuma variação do espanhol com o mesmo fenômeno.

Provavelmente alguém que estude português pode esclarecer melhor e colocar algumas referências.

Como regra que me funciona, eu palatalizo **/te/**, **/ti/**, **/de/** e **/di/** quando não são tônicas e deveriam soar como **/ti/** ou **/di/**, por exemplo:
*noite*,
*pode*,
*cátion*,
*código*.

Mas não usualmente quando é tônico por exemplo:
*tia*,
*cadela*,
*cadinho*.